# Body going off the screen?

Tags: html, css

The body appears to be going off the screen in firefox:
http://pila.isusing.us/sports-goal-posts/afl-goal-posts/

but on the home page it does not:
http://pila.isusing.us/

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me in Firefox 6.

Comment: Looks fine for me too.. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still baffled why this works, but while testing in Firefox 6:

```
.right-box div div div div div {display:none}
```

...made the scrollbar go away. I'm not sure what this affected, but I really couldn't see any visible changes other than the scroll bar on the bottom of the page disappearing.

I saw your issue in IE8 as well, but not Chrome. Hope this gets you on track to a solution.

I will say that while checking this out in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), there were a lot of unnecessary floats, clears, and widths declared, and your `<input>`s are acting strange in IE8. The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is also [throwing a fit](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpila.isusing.us%2Fsports-goal-posts%2Fafl-goal-posts%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) about your code. Might be time to refactor.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm using FF 5.0. I'm pretty much baffled. I'm pretty sure it's not something particularly obvious that's causing the error. :/

Answer (score 1):

It's `<div id="fb-root">`.  Inside a div "hides" with absolute positioning tricks, and that div contains an overly-wide iFrame.

As near as I can tell, setting `#fb-root { display: none; }` causes no loss of Facebook functionality, and solves the layout-busting problem.